# How to use rewriterules in .htaccess to change url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm using this rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ http://example.com/page?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I go to `example.com/page/somePage` I get redirected to `example.com/page?q=somePage`

But I don't want a redirection, what I want is the URL to always be `example.com/page/somePage`

How to do this?
Thank you

---

I removed http://example.com but it doesn't work, I get Page not Found.

---

I am using Wordpress for my site, this is my complete .htaccess:

---

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ page?q=$1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `[QSA,L]` flags at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you specify the `http://` at the beginning of the path to be rewritten to, Apache will *always* force a 301 redirect to the new URL, whether the URL is on the same website or not. Simply removing the `http://example.com` part should fix your problem.

---

As for the page not found, is there another RewriteRule somewhere that tells just 'page' to be processed as 'page.php' or something of the sort? Do you have your PHP files saved without extensions?

---

Well then your problem is you definitely need to remove the `[L]` flag because you're telling Apache not to process any more RewriteRules for that request, so it never looks at the WordPress rewrites because that rule was already executed and Apache was told that should be the final rule. I would recommend leaving the `[QSA]` in the line though, that would not affect the overall outcome of your script.